# HTTP GET передать два объекта

Tags: c#, winapi, http, asp.net-core, return

Не знаю как через Return передать и users и user2,а не только  user. Все перепробовал, помогите пожалуйста.

```
[HttpGet("{id}/{id2?}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Survey>> Get(int id, int id2)
        {
            Survey user = await db.Surveys.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            Survey user2 = await db.Surveys.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id2);
            if (user == null)
                return NotFound();

            return new ObjectResult(user);

        }
```

Comment: 1) сделать класс со свойствами `User1` и `User2` 2) Передать этот класс как результат

Comment: @tym32167 СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ •́  ‿ ,•̀ , из за этой лабуды уснуть не мог.

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшая реализация по моему мнению была бы использовать класс со свойствами User1 и User2 как сказал @tym32167.
Однако так же вы можете использовать кортеж, для этого просто объявите тип вида:

```
public Tuple<User, User> Method()
 {
     return new Tuple<User, User> { Item1 = User1, Item2 = User2 };
 }
```

Так же возможно реализация в виде `List<User>`

Comment: Чуть удобнее запись `return Tuple.Create(User1, User2);`, а в новом c# можно и `public (User, User) Method() { .... return (User1, User2);}`

Answer (score 0):

Если не требуется отдельной сущности под ответ, то так же можно использовать анонимный тип `new {}`. В нем можно управлять названиями полей.

```
[HttpGet("{id}/{id2?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id, int id2)
{
    Survey user = await db.Surveys.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    Survey user2 = await db.Surveys.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id2);
    if (user == null)
       return NotFound();

    return new ObjectResult(new {user, user2}); //or new {User1 = user, User2= user2 }
}
```

Как упомянул @tym32167, начиная с C# 7.0 можно использовать ValueTuple, но тут надо смотреть, сможет ли созданный объект сериализоваться. Вот [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1#serialization-and-value-tuples) говорит, что не во всех версиях возможна сериализация ValueTuple (хотя у меня и в Core 3.1 не сработала)